# OpenIdConnectAuthentication, used with Asp.net application goes to infinite loop for AuthorizationCodeReceived

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, openid, azure-active-directory

I am using Owin, OpenId authentication for my asp.net application to validate the users with Azure login. but once i login is done from azure and redirects, the AuthorizationCodeReceived goes into a infinite loop. Below is the code that i have used.

I have tried various suggestions from different posts as below but that has not helped me.

- https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3239
- [infinite loop going back to authentication page when using OAuth in MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168686/infinite-loop-going-back-to-authentication-page-when-using-oauth-in-mvc5)
- [Second sign-in causes infinite redirect loop after the first successful login MVC .NET 5 OWIN ADAL OpenIDConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747008/second-sign-in-causes-infinite-redirect-loop-after-the-first-successful-login-mv)
- setting the CallbackPath

  app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

  ```
      app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver(); //did not work
      app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
      {
          //CookieHttpOnly = false, 
          //CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest, //Did not work
          //CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager() //did not work
          AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
      }
      );
      app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
          new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
          {
              ClientId = clientId,
              Authority = authority,
              PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
              RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
              CallbackPath = new PathString("/my_Azure/Start.aspx"),

              Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
              {
                  //
                  // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                  //
                  AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                  {
                      var code = context.Code;
                      ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                      string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                      AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                      code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                      return Task.FromResult(0);
                  }
              }
          }
          );


      // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
      app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
  ```

Comment: Suspect this it is a code issue since the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) works for me. Does the code sample works for you?

Comment: The problem was with the authorization setting in web.config, i had used deny <deny users="*"/> this caused the application to deny all authorisation hence going in a loop, when i changed it to <deny users="?"/> it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the authorization setting in web.config, I had used deny `<deny users="*"/>` this caused the application to deny all authorization hence going in a loop, when I changed it to `<deny users="?"/>` it started worked fine.